# Angular monorepo, 1 shared login library component and 3 applications, how to specify application for login and change ev file?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, shared-libraries, monorepo

I have a shared login component and need to ID each application. I did this by changing the base url. That said, how do i change my ev files or is there a better method? I'm assuming I'd have to change some stuff server side and make the library ev file hold all 3 variables?

It's currently running, but not well. As you might imagine it redirects to a base url and you have to type in /whatever to get it to the correct page.

Is there an easier way than using urls?if urls are fine how do I fix my ev files?

Not sure if this is allowed, if not disregard, but I can try to pay a little for additional help outside this forum. I'm pretty desperate and can't find good resources